# how to prove function is not invertible

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

If I have a function like $f(x) = x^2$ or $f(x) = \sin(x)$ in the domain $[-\infty \infty]$, how can I prove that they are not invertible. I guess that this would involve proving that the function is bijective, but I get lost when I actually try to do that.

How can I prove that the functions above are not invertible?

Comment: Write down the domain and co-domain. As $x^2$ is invertible if I take $[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ but not invertible if I take $R\to R$

Comment: is this a suggestion for an edit or a suggestion about the proof?

Comment: If you can prove that the function is not bijective that is either not one-one or not onto then the function is not bijective.

Comment: @PNDas I understand what you said, but you just stated what I already knew in different words. I still am unclear in how to go about proving this

Comment: Suppose your function is $x^2:\mathit{R}\to\mathit{R}$. Then see negative numbers have no preimage as $x^2\geq 0$ Also $-1,1$ have same image so it is not one-one.So when doing for general function you take an arbitrary element from co-domain and see if it has a preimage or not. If it doesn't have preimage then $f$ is not onto. Similarly for one one case you first assume $f(x)=f(y)$ then try to prove $x=y$.If you succeed then $f$ is one-one.